# How to make changes to Woocommerce templates only for shop pages

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, woocommerce, conditional-statements

The question has been asked here before, but I found all solutions insufficient for what I’m trying to achieve.

The usual answer is to overwrite `archive-product.php` in your theme. However if you do this, you also overwrite the design for category pages.

For example with product categories you can overwrite a specific product_category with `product-cat-{slug}.php` I wonder if there is a possible way to just overwrite the main shop page of Woocommerce.

Answer (score 2):

When overriding templates, to make changes only for specific product archive pages, you can use WooCommerce (or WordPress) conditional tags. So in your case you will use `is_shop()`, inside your template code, a bit like:

```
if ( is_shop() ) {
    // Here add your customized code for shop pages
} else {
    // Here you keep original template code (optional)
}
```

Related documentation:

- [Available WooCommerce conditional tags](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/conditional-tags/#section-2)
- [Template structure & Overriding templates via a theme](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/)